# MemberwiseClone equivalent to an existing object?

Tags: c#, performance, memory-management

There are quite a few questions on here about MemberwiseClone, but I can't find anything covering this exactly.

As I understand it, MemberwiseClone basically just copies an area of memory for an object, dumps it somewhere else and calls it a new instance of that object. Obviously very quick, and for large objects it is the quickest way to make a copy. For small objects with simple constructors, it's quicker to create an instance and copy the individual properties.

Now, I have a tight loop in which I'm using MemberwiseClone. As MemberwiseClone always creates a new instance this leads to a lot of memory allocation, and reallocation which isn't great for performance.  I've written a custom copy for a very large object that copies all the properties individually onto an existing object, which overall is marginally quicker than using MemberwiseClone,

I feel that if I could grab the whole chunk of memory and dump it onto the existing object, I'd achieve a decent performance boost as the GC wouldn't have to worry about anything. Hopefully I'll also get rid of this message:

Just to clarify, I want to copy the properties from one existing object to another as quickly as possible. A shallow copy is all I need.

> Message   2   DA0023: (Average)% Time in GC = 19.30; 
>         % Time in GC is relatively high. This indication of excessive amount of garbage collection overhead could be impacting the
>   responsiveness of your application. You can gather .NET memory
>   allocation data and object lifetime information to understand the
>   pattern of memory allocation your application uses better.

I have no restrictions on code safety, speed is the aim of the game here.

No comments asking if this is really necessary or talking about premature optimisation please.

Thanks for your help.

### Answer

Taking the advise below, of embedding a struct within the object and storing all properties in that. I could then take a copy of that struct to copy all the properties in a single assignment. This yielded more than a 50% speed increase compared to copying field by field, and about a 60% speed increase over creating a new object every time with MemberwiseClone.

Comment: Is yours a class or a struct? What does it contains? Only primitive types or objects?

Comment: You are assuming that MemberwiseClone() does something else than "grab the whole chunk of memory".  It doesn't.  The issue is that you simply create too much garbage.  Cloning a lot will certainly do that.

Comment: @HansPassant That's exactly what I'm assuming MemberwiseClone does. And that's what I want to be able to do without creating the garbage that cloning to a new object creates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your class is not inheritable, you could store the entire state of your class in an exposed-field structure (expose fields, not properties!).  This would require that you prefix all field names with the name of the structure, which would be ugly in the source code, but accessing fields in that structure will be just as fast as would be accessing fields that were directly placed in the enclosing class.  Doing this, however, will gain you the ability to copy the structure from one object instance into another using a simple assignment statement.

Comment: He could make the properties of the class "proxies" of the fields of the struct, and use the struct only to directly copy it to a new class.

Comment: That looks like it might be worth a try

Comment: @WillCalderwood Changed the pastebin to include a minumum of comments

Comment: @xanatos: That's the basic idea.  One thing to watch out for, though, is that accessing nested structure *fields* is efficient, no matter how big the structures are, but accessing structure *properties* can be very inefficient.  For example, if `Quad<T1>` is an exposed-field struct with four exposed fields of type `T1`, and `v` is a mutable variable of type `Quad<Quad<Quad<Quad<Int32>>>>` (holding 256 integers), then `int temp = v.v1.v3.v4.v1` will be a single integer load, but if `v` was a property or `readonly` variable, that expression would...

Comment: ...have to make a copy of `v` (1024 bytes), then a copy of `v.v1` (256 bytes), then a copy of `v.v1.v3` (64 bytes), then a copy of `v1.v3.v4` (16 bytes), before finally being able to read the desired integer.  Large structures can be very efficient if one uses them carefully, but very inefficient if one lets the system insert implicit copy operations.

Comment: Just ran some tests for accessing fields and properties. Incrementing a field within the object 1000000000 times took ~2500ms on average. Incrementing a property which points to a field in a struct took ~2200ms on average. Incrementing the struct directly took ~1900ms. I don't understand the overhead of accessing the field directly. Looks like a public struct is fastest though.

Comment: I don't know if you timed a release build with the debugger detached, but you should be aware that it's possible for some method X to run twice as fast as Y when code is launched under the debugger, but for Y to run twice as fast as X when the program is launched outside the debugger.

Comment: @supercat I never to performance tests in debug mode or with the debugger attached, so neither of those were the cause.

Comment: Time for 10000000 copies dropped from ~1830ms to ~900ms. Over a 50% speed boost from storing properties in a struct and taking a copy of that instead of copying field by field.  I knew there was a speed boost to be had here!

Comment: @xanatos Don't know if you're still keeping an eye on this, but I thought you might be interested in the results (Added to the question). Thanks for your help.

Comment: @WillCalderwood: Perhaps there should be some acronym people can use when mentioning benchmarks to indicate they know they're useless in Debug mode. >:*3  The "mutable structs are evil" mantra ignores the fact that exposed-field structures can often allow one to write code which is both faster and clearer than any alternative, though I wish there was an easy way to indicate that a type should regard members of an encapsulated struct as being its own [without having to manually forward every member].

Answer (score 2):

In general you can't be faster than doing a copy field by field.

This in general. There is a single exception: if your class is blittable (so doesn't contain any reference to non-blittable classes) AND it's declared with the     `[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]` (or with the `[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]`, but it's more complex to test) then you can pin it

```
GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(refToYourClass, GCHandleType.Pinned);
```

from there a new world opens... You can directly copy byte-by-byte the content of your class with some unsafe (both as `unsafe` the keyboard and *unsafe* as "running-with-scissors") code.

BUT for this to work, your class MUST be blittable!

The fastest method is `UnsafeCopy8` that copies blocks of 8 bytes (both at 32bits and at 64bits). The fastest PInvoke method is `memcpy`.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
class MyClass
{
    public int A { get; set; }
    public int B { get; set; }
    public int C { get; set; }
    public int D { get; set; }
    public int E { get; set; }
    public int F { get; set; }
    public int G { get; set; }
    public byte H { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    [DllImport("msvcrt.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, SetLastError = false)]
    static extern IntPtr memcpy(IntPtr dest, IntPtr src, UIntPtr count);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = false)]
    static extern void CopyMemory(IntPtr dest, IntPtr src, UIntPtr count);

    static void Main()
    {
        MyClass mc = new MyClass { A = 1, B = 2, C = 3, D = 4, E = 5, F = 6, G = 7, H = 8 };
        MyClass mc2 = new MyClass();

        int size = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(MyClass));

        var gc = GCHandle.Alloc(mc, GCHandleType.Pinned);
        var gc2 = GCHandle.Alloc(mc2, GCHandleType.Pinned);

        IntPtr dest = gc2.AddrOfPinnedObject();
        IntPtr src = gc.AddrOfPinnedObject();

        // Pre-caching
        memcpy(dest, src, (UIntPtr)size);
        CopyMemory(dest, src, (UIntPtr)size);
        UnsafeCopy(dest, src, size);
        UnsafeCopy8(dest, src, size);

        int cycles = 10000000;

        Process.GetCurrentProcess().PriorityClass = ProcessPriorityClass.High;

        var sw1 = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        for (int i = 0; i < cycles; i++)
        {
            memcpy(dest, src, (UIntPtr)size);
        }

        sw1.Stop();

        var sw2 = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        for (int i = 0; i < cycles; i++)
        {
            CopyMemory(dest, src, (UIntPtr)size);
        }

        sw2.Stop();

        var sw3 = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        for (int i = 0; i < cycles; i++)
        {
            UnsafeCopy(dest, src, size);
        }

        sw3.Stop();

        var sw4 = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        for (int i = 0; i < cycles; i++)
        {
            UnsafeCopy8(dest, src, size);
        }

        sw4.Stop();

        gc.Free();
        gc2.Free();

        Console.WriteLine("IntPtr.Size: {0}", IntPtr.Size);
        Console.WriteLine("memcpy:      {0}", sw1.ElapsedTicks);
        Console.WriteLine("CopyMemory:  {0}", sw2.ElapsedTicks);
        Console.WriteLine("UnsafeCopy:  {0}", sw3.ElapsedTicks);
        Console.WriteLine("UnsafeCopy8: {0}", sw4.ElapsedTicks);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static unsafe void UnsafeCopy(IntPtr dest, IntPtr src, int size)
    {
        while (size >= sizeof(int))
        {
            *((int*)dest) = *((int*)src);

            dest = (IntPtr)(((byte*)dest) + sizeof(int));
            src = (IntPtr)(((byte*)src) + sizeof(int));
            size -= sizeof(int);
        }

        if (size >= sizeof(short))
        {
            *((short*)dest) = *((short*)src);

            dest = (IntPtr)(((byte*)dest) + sizeof(short));
            src = (IntPtr)(((byte*)src) + sizeof(short));
            size -= sizeof(short);
        }

        if (size == sizeof(byte))
        {
            *((byte*)dest) = *((byte*)src);
        }
    }

    static unsafe void UnsafeCopy8(IntPtr dest, IntPtr src, int size)
    {
        while (size >= sizeof(long))
        {
            *((long*)dest) = *((long*)src);

            dest = (IntPtr)(((byte*)dest) + sizeof(long));
            src = (IntPtr)(((byte*)src) + sizeof(long));
            size -= sizeof(long);
        }

        if (size >= sizeof(int))
        {
            *((int*)dest) = *((int*)src);

            dest = (IntPtr)(((byte*)dest) + sizeof(int));
            src = (IntPtr)(((byte*)src) + sizeof(int));
            size -= sizeof(int);
        }

        if (size >= sizeof(short))
        {
            *((short*)dest) = *((short*)src);

            dest = (IntPtr)(((byte*)dest) + sizeof(short));
            src = (IntPtr)(((byte*)src) + sizeof(short));
            size -= sizeof(short);
        }

        if (size == sizeof(byte))
        {
            *((byte*)dest) = *((byte*)src);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you've misunderstood the question. I'm trying to reuse objects, but I need a fast way to copy the properties from one object to another.

Comment: @WillCalderwood Changed response

Comment: Thanks for that. Unfortunately I do have non-blittable types in the class. :-(